# HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, tomcat6

I deployed my project on the production server and getting the below error.

It's a live project so , after getting error i replaced this with previous version that was running fine but now that is also throwing the same error.Please suggest me what could be the problem ?

error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:821)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.LPSSuppIndex_jsp._jspService(LPSSuppIndex_jsp.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:124)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:821)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.LPSSuppIndex_jsp._jspService(LPSSuppIndex_jsp.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
```

IndexPage.jsp :

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import = "jdbc.RetrieveLangList,lang.MessageGetter" %>
<%!
    HashMap<String, String> langListMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
%>
<%
        //Retrieving language MAP
        RetrieveLangList objList = new RetrieveLangList();
        langListMap = objList.LangList();
        Set s = langListMap.entrySet(); // Get hashmap in Set interface to get key and value
        Iterator it = s.iterator(); // Move next key and value of HashMap by iterator

        String suppLang = "en_US";
        suppLang = request.getParameter("suppLanguage");
        if (suppLang == null || suppLang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            suppLang = "en_US";
%>
<html>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Welcome to  </TITLE>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="image/H.ico"/>
<LINK href="image/css/Rcontent.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</HEAD>
<script language="JavaScript">
function loadPage(list)
{
  location.href=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
}
</script>
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
    function ValidateForm()
    {
    //Supplier Number Validation
    var supp_number =document.loginForm.uname;

    if((supp_number.value=="su")||(supp_number.value=="SU"))
        {
            return true;
        }

    var stripped = supp_number.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, ''); 
    if((supp_number.value==null)||(supp_number.value==""))
        {
        alert("<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "Enter_User_ID")%>");
        supp_number.focus();
        return false;
        }
    else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        alert("<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "Invalid_User_ID")%>");
        supp_number.focus();
        return false;
         }

        //Password Validation
        var supp_pass =document.loginForm.pass;
    if((supp_pass.value==null)||(supp_pass.value==""))
        {
        alert("<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "Enter_Password")%>");
        //alert("Please Enter Password");
        supp_pass.focus();
        return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
</SCRIPT>
<BODY bgcolor="#C7CACF">
<center>
<table border = "0" bordercolor = "black" style="background-image:url('image/backgroundIndex.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat" width="1000" HEIGHT = "700" >
<tr height = "60">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">
    <form name="form1" >
    <TABLE border="0" width = "610">
    <TR>
       <td width="300" align="right" height="40">
            <select name="file" size="1" onchange="loadPage(this.form.elements[0])" target="_parent._top"  onmouseclick="this.focus()" style="background-color: #ffffff;width:150px;"> <!-- This is language selection box -->
            <%
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) it.next(); // key=value separator this by Map.Entry to get key and value
                //System.out.println("value : "+m.getValue()+" key : "+m.getKey());
                if(suppLang.equals(m.getKey()))
                {
            %>
            <option value="LPSSuppIndex.jsp?suppLanguage=<%= m.getKey()%>" selected="selected"><%= m.getValue()%></option>
            <%
                }
                else
                {
            %>
            <option value="LPSSuppIndex.jsp?suppLanguage=<%= m.getKey()%>"><%= m.getValue()%></option>
            <%
                }
            }
            %>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td width = "300px" align="right"><a HREF="mailto:?subject=<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "sub_contact")%>&body=<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line1_contact")%>, %0D%0D%0D<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line2_contact")%>, %0D%0D%0D<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line3_contact")%>%0D%0D%0D"><font color="#73767B" size="2"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "contact")%></font></a><font color="#73767B"><B> |</B></font><a href="http://www..com/en/service/imprint-legal-issues.html"><font color="#73767B" size="2"> <%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "imprint_legel_issue")%></font></a><font color="#73767B"><B> | </B></font><a href="http://www..com/en/service/sitemap.html"><font color="#73767B" size="2"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "sitemap")%></font></a></td>
    </TR>
    <TR height="12px">
        <TD colspan="2">&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
     <td height = "240px" valign="top">
        <TABLE border="0" width = "195">
        <TR>
            <TD height="40" width="155" align="left"><div style="position:relative;left: 20px;"><a href="LPSSuppIndex.jsp"><font color="#73767B" size="3"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "home")%></font></a></div></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD height="37" align="left"><div style="position:relative;left: 20px;"><A HREF="mailto:er_Admin@de..com?subject=<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "sub_contact")%>&body=<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line1_contact")%>, %0D%0D%0D<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line2_contact")%>, %0D%0D%0D<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line3_contact")%>%0D%0D%0D"><font color="#73767B"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "contact")%></font></a></div></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD height="35" align="left"><div style="position:relative;left: 20px;"><a href="LPSSuppIndex.jsp"><font color="#73767B" size="3"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "log_in")%></font></a></div></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD height="34" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://wwwcom"><font color="white" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "tportal")%></font></a></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD height = "32" align="center">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD height = "43px" colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>

        </TABLE>
    </td>

    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
        <table border="0px" >
            <tr height="139px"><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr height="431px">
                <td valign="top" width="8px"><div class="vertical-line" style="position:relative;left:27px;top:0px;"></div></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <!-- START RIGHT CONTENT  -->

                    <DIV class="cntr_cnt_gradbox" style="position: relative;left: 15px;top: -5px;">
                    <DIV class="cntr_head"><font size="2%"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "PDF_download")%>&nbsp;</font></DIV>
                    <DIV class="cntr_cnt_gradbox_inner">
                        <DIV class="cntr_frame" style="height: 60px;">
                            <DIV style="FLOAT: left;height: 50px;" >
                                <IMG src="image/PDF_Thumbnail_50x50.gif" border="0">
                            </DIV>
                            <DIV class="cntr_dl_cnt" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 55px;">
                                <A class="cntr_lnk" href="PDF/User Maner_EN.pdf" target="_blank"><font color="#73767B" size="2%"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "manual_en")%></font></A>
                            </DIV>&nbsp;
                            <BR class="clr">
                        </DIV>
                        <BR class="clr">
                        <DIV class="cntr_frame" style="height: 60px;">
                            <DIV style="FLOAT: left;height: 50px;" >
                                <IMG src="image/PDF_Thumbnail_50x50.gif" border="0">
                            </DIV>
                            <DIV class="cntr_dl_cnt" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 55px;">
                                <A class="cntr_lnk" href="PDF/Benutzerhl Printer_DE.pdf" target="_blank"><font color="#73767B" size="2%"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "manual_de")%></font></A>
                            </DIV>&nbsp;
                            <BR class="clr">
                        </DIV>
                        <BR class="clr">
                        <DIV class="cntr_frame" style="height: 60px;">
                            <DIV style="FLOAT: left;height: 50px;" >
                                <IMG src="image/PDF_Thumbnail_50x50.gif" border="0">
                            </DIV>
                            <DIV class="cntr_dl_cnt" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 55px;">
                                <A class="cntr_lnk" href="PDF/Print_Specification.pdf" target="_blank" title="<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "printHelp_tip")%>"><font color="#73767B" size="2%"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "printHelp")%></font></A>
                            </DIV>
                            <BR class="clr">
                        </DIV>
                        <DIV class="cntr_frame1" style="height: 30px;">
                             <div style="margin-left: 30px;"> <A class="cntr_lnk" href="PDF/quick_guide_en.pdf" target="_blank"><font color="#73767B" size="2%"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "one_point_lessons")%> - EN</font></A></div>
                        </DIV>

                        <DIV class="cntr_frame1" style="height: 30px;">
                             <div style="margin-left: 30px;"> <A class="cntr_lnk" href="PDF/quick_guide_de.pdf" target="_blank"><font color="#73767B" size="2%"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "one_point_lessons")%> - DE</font></A></div>
                        </DIV>
                        <DIV style="height: 30px;vertical-align: middle;">
                             <div style="margin-left: 30px;"> <A class="cntr_lnk" href="PDF/FAQ.pdf" target="_blank"><font color="#73767B" size="2%">FAQ</font></A></div>
                        </DIV>
                        </DIV>
                    </DIV>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr height = "210">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
     <form method="post" name="loginForm" action="./loginServlet" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()">
     <input type="hidden" name="selectedLang" value="<%=suppLang%>" >
     <TABLE border="0" bordercolor="black" width="370">
     <tr><td rowspan="6" width = "30">&nbsp;</td></tr>

     <TR height="45">
        <td width="110" ><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "user_id")%> : </td><!-- This is Supplier Number(User ID) entry field. -->
     <td width="230" align="center"><input type="text" size="25" name="uname" style="border-color: #529DFA;" maxlength="10"></td>
     </TR>
     <TR>
     <td height="45"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "Password")%> : </td><!-- This is Password entry field. -->
      <td align="center"><input type="password" size="25" name="pass" style="border-color: #529DFA;"></td>
     </TR>
     <TR height="40">
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td align ="center" height="40"><A HREF="mailto_Printer_Admin@de.h.com?subject=<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "sub_forget_password")%>&body=<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line1_forget_password")%>, %0D%0D%0D<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "body_line2_forget_password")%>%0D%0D%0D"><%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "forget_password")%></A>
    </td>
     </TR>
     <TR>   
     <td height="40" align="right"><input type="Submit" value="<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "log_in")%>" /> </td>
     <td align="center"><input type="button" onClick="location.href='register/suppRegistration.jsp?selectedLang=<%=suppLang%>'" value="<%=MessageGetter.getMessage("lang.MessagesBundle", suppLang, "new_user")%>" /></td>
     </TR>
     </TABLE></form>
     </td>
</tr>

<tr height = "114">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width = "200">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="170">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="380">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="230" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: NullPointerException is a code error, you are trying to access a null object. Better post servlet code also for getting the right help.

Comment: show also the LPSSuppIndex.jsp code, there must be a null object there

Comment: NOthing to do with `jar's` here, Post the Jsp code causing error.

Comment: provious version was working fine ... so why that one also not working now ?

Comment: Also check your log.... "note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs."

Comment: @suresh atta : ... that was just a query

Comment: @NibhaJain  That is ok, What about the Changes you made newly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Tomcat a .java and .class file will be created for every jsp files with in the application and the same can be found from the path below,
`Apache-Tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\'ApplicationName'\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java`

In your case the jsp name is error.jsp so the path should be something like below
`Apache-Tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\'ApplicationName'\org\apache\jsp\error_jsp.java` in line no 124 you are trying to access a null object which results in null pointer exception.

Comment: Is there a way to clean that directory ? So that i would be able to run at least the previous version ?

Comment: @NibhaJain ,yes you can delete it, if you are copying your webapplication to Tomcat `webapps` folder manually then shutdown tomcat delete you application war and the deployed folder, also delete the application folder from `work\Catalina\localhost`. If you have deployed it using `tomcat manager console` undeploy will delete the work folder of your application too. I would recommend deleting it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much .. atleast the live one is working now ... i can check the problems without tension ;)

Comment: @NibhaJain, would like to add info about the exception you are getting `indexpage.jsp` is told to display `error.jsp` on any error in it, hope `indexpage.jsp` is your welcome file which loads on application launch, which has error and the error.jsp to be loaded is looking for some objects which is null as the application failed to load the  welcome file(`indexpage.jsp`).

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException with JSP ***can also happen if***:

A getter returns a **non-public inner class**.

This code will fail if you remove **Getters**'s access modifier or make it private or protected.

JAVA:

```
package com.myPackage;
public class MyClass{ 
    //: Must be public or you will get:
    //: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 
    //: java.lang.NullPointerException
    public class Getters{
        public String 
        myProperty(){ return(my_property); }
    };;

    //: JSP EL can only access functions:
    private Getters _get;
    public  Getters  get(){ return _get; }

    private String 
    my_property;

    public MyClass(String my_property){
        super();
        this.my_property    = my_property;
        _get = new Getters();
    };;
};;
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri   ="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="com.myPackage.MyClass" %>
<%
    MyClass inst = new MyClass("[PROP_VALUE]");
    pageContext.setAttribute("my_inst", inst ); 
%><html lang="en"><body>
    ${ my_inst.get().myProperty() }
</body></html>
```